# How do I pass parameters from an xquery file to another xquery file?

Tags: xquery, marklogic

I'm looking at code that's not written by me. There is a Javascript function that passes coordinates to an xquery file through the browser.

Example:
http://localhost/mymap.html?lat=123&lon=123

The file mymap.html is an xquery file called mymap.xqy. Is there a way to just pass the lat lon parameters from another xquery file?

Comment: Can you elaborate on how that works? This is confusing: "mymap.html is an xquery file called mymap.xqy".

Comment: I think it's how you can render xqy files in the browser. For example, I can go to localhost/test.html if I have an xqy file called test.xqy. The following will print hello world in the browser from test.xqy.version "1.0-ml";

let $helloWorld := "hello world"
return $helloWorld

Comment: It doesn't work that way out of the box. It is possible to use a rewriter to rewrite URLs to whatever you want, so I assume that's what is going on. It's still unclear what you want to do. "pass the lat lon parameters from another xquery file"?...To where? Pass the parameters in `mymap.xqy` to `some-other.xqy`?

Comment: Ah thanks! It looks like there was a rewriter.